# Place div with overlay to left one

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap grid and have to place many div-tags inside one cell. All this div-tags should overlay to the left one. The count of div-tags of the cell is variable.

Example: All div-tags have an example content *[abcd]* -> the result at the page should be: **[ab[ab[ab[abcd]**
*(But not by manipulating the text - it could be an image too - the divs have to be placed with overlay)*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="myClass">[abcd]</div>
    <div class="myClass">[abcd]</div>
    <div class="myClass">[abcd]</div>
    <div class="myClass">[abcd]</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8"></div>
</div>
```

I tried it by putting manually *position:relative* or *position:absolute* styles with *left:20px* or *left:-20px*. But then they overlay over other cells. 
In some cases I've to do this overlay vertical, with manual styles I got more "overlay-columns" than one.

How to handle this?

Comment: See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the `z-index` CSS property will help.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index